# Some transparent textures in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, textures

> Some textures are transparent when I render them out in the browser. Is there a way to solve this issue? Im just started learing Three.js.

[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPzCH.png)

```
loader.load(model, (object) =\>
{
object.position.set(-0.8,-0.5,-0.2)
scene.add(object)
scene.add(pointLight)
renderer.render(scene, camera);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
camera.position.z = 2;
camera.position.y = 1;
camera.position.x = 2.8;

    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    }
    animate();

}
```

Tried with multiple models but always same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those areas are transparent because you're looking at the back-face of your geometry. Rendering the back-face is disabled by default, but you can enable it on your material:

```js
object.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

You can read more about `Material.side` [in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=material#api/en/materials/Material.side).